# Your recent binary submission to the App Store -

Tags: iphone, xcode, configuration, distribution

After I submit  my app via archive , 
**I test in my iphone and I use distribution configuration before i publish**
I received email from app store :

Invalid Signature - Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.

Once you have corrected these issues, go to the app's version details page (found in the Manage Your Applications module of iTunes Connect) and click Ready to Submit Binary. Proceed through the submission process until the app's status is Waiting for Upload. You can then use Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.

Comment: And now we have to guess your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error lots of time with same reason every time. I just resolved it by selecting my distribution profile in target and project level both. I don't know if it is correct solution or not but it solved my problem every time. So just try to select distribution certificate in all the debug, release and distribution configuration. See attached screenshot if you are using xCode 4

[image].

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

just make new build & upload it to appstore again but make sure in active target you have used distribution certificates :)